# Nesting SQL query inside R function

Tags: r, sql-server

I would like to write an R function that holds a SQL query so they can call the name of the query, then change a few basic conditions in the WHERE clause (like a date).  I'm also developing an R package for my team to use so they can just call the query they want, change a few things without needing to know SQL, and manipulate the data from there.

I've written a few basic functions in R, but the quasi-quotation thing is throwing me off.  I'm just wondering if anyone has already done this and could send over the syntax?

```
SQLquery <- function(chooseSQLqry) {
  chosenQry <- editWHEREclause <- function(date) {
    SQL query goes here?
  }
}
```

Comment: You may try `glue_sql()`: https://glue.tidyverse.org/reference/glue_sql.html